# Convenient single-key remapping for PageUp and PageDown in Vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

As many laptop and even desktop keyboards lack dedicated <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> keys, or those are placed in awkward positions, I am thinking to remap in Vim the <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd> keys as <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> so I can conveniently scroll with a single keystroke.

I wonder if there is perhaps other useful combinations? For example, like remapping <kbd>B</kbd> as <kbd>PageUp</kbd> to be compatible with `less` and other viewers, and remapping <kbd>B</kbd> to some other key. Or even remap <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> as <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd>. Any other useful combinations?

Comment: did you know that there is a stack exchange for vim? you might get more help there https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of shortcuts for navigating around. Here are some useful ones:

- `Ctrl-u`: Go up half a screen.
- `Ctrl-d`: Go down half a screen.
- `Ctrl-b`: Go up one full screen.
- `Ctrl-f`: Go down one full screen.

Comment: The question is about single-keystroke shortcuts. Ctrl-something is not.

Comment: Well sure, you could map it to one of the function keys, but I think overwriting single keys is bad practice in VIM as it will not let you use vanilla VIM once you encounter it and does obscure other core functions of VIM behind unconventional keybindings. These bindings are part of vanilla VIM and are not that hard to hit. You should always be able to hit the letter with one hand while pressing the `Ctrl` button with the other, making them equally fast as a single key binding (if both hands are on the keyboard of course).

Comment: I would not bother with the question if Ctrl-something would suite me. Just consider a case when one is reviewing a code while holding a cup with some beverage.

Answer (score 2):

Let's remember that the `<S-Up>` and `<S-Down>` keypresses are recognized in `vim` and mapped by default to `<PageUp>` and `<PageDown>`, respectively.  In other words, the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> keypresses can be used in `vim` instead of the <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> keys, respectively.

However, depending on the terminal emulator you're using, you may actually need to properly handle the escape sequences generated for the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> keypresses to make the scrolling work. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/how-to-fix-ctrl-arrows-in-vim) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/753395/581311) for rather detailed instructions and a bit of background information, but please be prepared to spend some time on it.

Obviously, the OP's question was about scrolling one page up or down in `vim` using single keys on a laptop keyboard, but let's keep in mind that the arrow keys are virtually always in very close proximity to the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key on laptop keyboards.  Thus, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> on a laptop keyboard with just one hand isn't bad at all, with the important additional benefit of introducing no non-standard `vim` mappings.

Sticking to some kind of an already established standard should be good in this case, at least because you'll feel at home when you find yourself using bone-stock `vim` on someone else's laptop.